# Wget 403 Forbidden, But works in every browser

Tags: javascript, linux, download, wget

File: `EssentialsX-2.18.1.0.jar`

Command:

```
wget "https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/essentialsx/files/latest"
```

Output:

```
--2020-09-22 07:49:22--  https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/essentialsx/files/latest
Resolving dev.bukkit.org (dev.bukkit.org)... 104.19.146.132, 104.19.147.132, 2606:4700::6813:9284, ...
Connecting to dev.bukkit.org (dev.bukkit.org)|104.19.146.132|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-09-22 07:49:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: It might be the user-agent header

Comment: Can you explain me how?

Comment: Like this: wget -U "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)" "https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/essentialsx/files/latest", It might be that the URL itself is wrong tho and that a script/redirect maked the browser download the file, did you try wget "https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/essentialsx/files/latest/EssentialsX-2.18.1.0.jar" ???

Comment: You mean like "dev.bukkit.org/projects/essentialsx/files/latestEssentialsX-2.18.1.0.jar" . But that also return 403...

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation of the issue I came to this conclusion:

**The website uses cloudflare and hcaptcha to verify that the client is a human.** **Hence it will never work with wget**

Behind the scenes it loads this:
https://dev.bukkit.org/cdn-cgi/scripts/hcaptcha.challenge.js

which would automatically run some code in your browser to verify that you indeed are not a robot, this can most probably not be bypassed with wget.

The site basically requires you to download the file as a human and have outsourced the job to verify this.

Comment: Thank you for your great effort, May be i have to find other tools like selenium to do the job.Thanks